# Will a static in a lib be the same value for all objects?

Tags: c++, static, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Let's say I am trying to generate a process specific id:

```
class TestLib
{
  public:
  static int n;

  static int generate_id(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    if (n == 0)
    n = rand() % 10 + 1;

    return n;
  };
};
```

And I have libs A and B that include TestLib:

```
class TEST_A
{
  public:
    static void print() {
      std::cout << "A" << TestLib::generate_id() << std::endl;
    };
};

class TEST_B
{
  public:
    static void print() {
      std::cout << "B" << TestLib::generate_id() << std::endl;
    };
};
```

Will I be guaranteed that any single process using either A and B will have the same id?

Will this change if I linked the libraries statically?

I have tested this in linux-x86 with shared objects, but I'm not sure how safe this is in principle.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not guaranteed that unless your program is single-threaded. Otherwise two concurrent calls to `generate_id` could possibly override each other's results.

Answer (score 0):

Regular (linked) libraries will share their static variables, but dynamic libraries will each get their own copy.

Hopefully you have something in a source file that initializes `n` to zero.

Comment: No need to init n to zero, all global (static) variables are defined to 0 (int), false (bool), NULL (pointer).